# How To Split First & Last Name String From Full Name In Android

Tags: android, string

I have a form with a full-name `EditText` field and I would like to break the string into a first and last name strings .  Can any one help me on this? May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

If user enter his/her name like `A B C` . First name will be `A` & Last Name Will `BC`

I am trying This :

```
EditText UNSP =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserNameToSIGNUP);
    String UserFullName=UNSP.getText().toString();

    String[] arr=UserFullName.split(" ");

    String fname=arr[0];
    String lname=arr[1];

    Log.d("First name",fname);
    Log.d("last name",lname);



    if(UserFullName.length()==0) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Submit Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else{

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 33):

In case you need only last and first name from full name without using array this is best approach in my point of view. First name can be on two or more than two words but last name always on one word in real world.

```
    String name = "Abdul Latif Hussain"
    String lastName = "";
    String firstName= "";
    if(name.split("\\w+").length>1){

       lastName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
       firstName = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(' '));
    }
     else{
       firstName = name;
    }
```

Output String will be:
firstName= "Abdul Latif"
lastName = "Hussain"

Comment: Many thanks for showing response . Your logic perfect .Happy coding

Comment: and if it ends with jr?

Comment: don't forget to trim name before splitting, otherwise works great

Answer (score 7):

For multiple names, it's better to just have separate `EditTexts` for each field.

For your implementation, If you can guarantee that they enter it in that format, you can just go:

```
int firstSpace = UserFullName.indexOf(" "); // detect the first space character
String firstName = UserFullName.substring(0, firstSpace);  // get everything upto the first space character
String lastName = UserFullName.substring(firstSpace).trim(); // get everything after the first space, trimming the spaces off
```

just put some error checking to ensure the format is right, otherwise you may get exceptions

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1  Showing this error

Comment: @Amiya The way I did it in my answer is to replace what you did with `String.split()`. The code above will not throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if your string doesn't contain spaces. Looks like the error is elsewhere

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, I came up with the following solution:

```
val displayName = "John Smith Fidgerold Trump"
var parts  = displayName.split(" ").toMutableList()
val firstName = parts.firstOrNull()
parts.removeAt(0)
val lastName = parts.joinToString(" ")
Log.debug("*** displayName: $displayName")
Log.debug("*** firsteName : $firstName")
Log.debug("*** lastName : $lastName")
Log.debug("**************")
```

Sample output:

```
> ** displayName: John Smith Fidgerold Trump
> ** firsteName : John
> ** lastName   : Smith Fidgerold Trump
> *************
> ** displayName: John Smith Fidgerold
> ** firsteName : John
> ** lastName   : Smith Fidgerold
> *************
> ** displayName: John Smith
> ** firsteName : John
> ** lastName   : Smith
> *************
> ** displayName: John
> ** firsteName : John
> ** lastName   : 
> *************
> ** displayName: 
> ** firsteName : 
> ** lastName   : 
> *************
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use `String.split(" ").` This will create separated strings, each one ending when the `" "` char is found.

Comment: Try using "\\s" instead of " "

Answer (score 1):

Please use this. It will work 100%

```
str = UNSP.getText().toString();
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

For only first name:

```
 public static void getUserFirstName(String fullname){
    String firstName;
    String[] fullNameArray = fullname.split("\\s+");
    if(fullNameArray.length>1) {
        StringBuilder firstNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < fullNameArray.length - 1; i++) {
            firstNameBuilder.append(fullNameArray[i]);
            if(i != fullNameArray.length - 2){
                firstNameBuilder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        firstName = firstNameBuilder.toString();
    }
    else{
        firstName = fullNameArray[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin** version:

```
val fullName = "Adriatik Gashi"
val idx = fullName.lastIndexOf(' ')
if (idx == -1) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid full name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      return
}

val firstName = fullName.substring(0, idx)
val lastName = fullName.substring(idx + 1)
Log.e("SPLITED NAME", firstName + " - " + lastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun getShortName(value: String): String {
    value.trim().apply {
        if (isBlank() || length <= 2) {
            return this
        }
        return if (contains(" "))
            split(" ").first().first().toString() + split(" ").last().first().toString()
        else
            take(2)
    }
}
```

Use this to get short Name like
Input = Yasir Tanveer
Output = YT