# Split First and Last word from string in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have some strings that I want to split into first and last names. I tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377241). But I only want the first and last word from the string.

**For example**

**Scenario 1**

```
val string = "Vivek Modi"
```

**Scenario 2**

```
val string = "Vivek  Modi "
```

**Scenario 3 after the first name I added space**

```
val string = "Vivek  Modi"
```

**Scenario 4 after the last name I added space**

```
val string = "Vivek Modi "
```

**Scenario 5 after the last name I added space**

```
val string = "Vivek XYZ Modi "
```

**Expected output**

```
firstName = Vivek

lastName = Modi
```

I tried this code

```
val displayName = "Vivek Modi "
val parts  = displayName.split(" ").toMutableList()
val firstName = parts.firstOrNull()
parts.removeAt(0)
val lastName = parts.lastOrNull()
println("*** displayName: $displayName")
println("*** firstName : $firstName")
println("*** lastName : $lastName")
```

**Getting Output**

```
*** displayName: Vivek Modi 
*** firstName : Vivek
*** lastName :
```

Is there any better way to solve this situation. Thanks

Comment: Look at Regex !!!

Comment: Just remember, that you may not get the whole last or first name, regardless how you split...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
fun splitName(name: String): Pair<String?, String?> {
    val names = name.trim().split(Regex("\\s+"))
    return names.firstOrNull() to names.lastOrNull()
}
```

The `trim` method removes any leading/trailing space from the string (covering scenarios 2, 4 and 5) and the `split` method with the regular expression `\s+` splits the string by one (scenario 1) or more (scenarios 2 and 3) white spaces. Here's some tests:

```
val scenarios = arrayOf("Vivek Modi", "Vivek  Modi ", "Vivek  Modi", "Vivek Modi ", "Vivek XYZ Modi ")
scenarios.forEach { input ->
    val (firstName, lastName) = splitName(input)
    assert(firstName == "Vivek")
    assert(lastName == "Modi")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved on enzo answer. You can add the below code in your extension file this will help with scenario 5. You can further improve the code to handle middle name by not combining firtNameSplit and adding it to a new variable

```
val (firstName, lastName) = fullName.splitName()
```

firstName will be Vivek XYZ and lastName will be Modi

```
fun String.splitName(): Pair<String?, String?> {
    val names = this.trim().split(Regex("\\s+"))
    if(names.size == 1){
        return names.firstOrNull() to ""
    }
    else if(names.size >= 3){
        var firstName = ""
        var firstNameSize = names.size - 1;
        names.forEachIndexed { index, firstNameSplit ->
            if(index < firstNameSize){
                firstName = "$firstName $firstNameSplit"
            }
        }
        return firstName to names.lastOrNull()
    }
    return names.firstOrNull() to names.lastOrNull()
}
```